# Instead of getting reputation points, I lose it, and badges won't come

Tags: bug, reputation, badges

I am having problems with badges and reputation points. I tried to get the "first downvote" badge (bronze), but it just doesn't come. And the problem with reputation points is that my answers got marked as accepted and upvoted, but I lose my reputation points for some reason. I lose a small amount on it, but it is still something. Maybe it is just some coincidence, but I do not know. About hour ago I had 160 reputation points, but now 155. And it is not for the first time.

Comment: Badges don't come immediately. They are awarded by scripts that run at regular intervals.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Ooh, thank you for telling that I really didn't know that. But what about the rep?

Comment: Okay, I think some kind of remove thing was the issue.

Answer (score 7):

For the [Critic badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7/critic), you need *yourself* to downvote somebody else's post. You have 125 reputation, so you do have the privilege, and it shouldn't be that hard to find something worth downvoting. If you already did so, the badge should arrive in an hour or so - most badges are not awarded instantaneously.

As for losing your reputation: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3848797/tarvo-m%C3%A4esepp?tab=reputation) you can check what happens with your reputation. I see some downvotes and a bounty you posted, but nothing out of the ordinary. It could be that somebody upvoted a question of yours, and within a couple of minutes reverted that decision and canceled his/her upvote.

Also, it could be that you had a question with a score of 1 was deleted - you can check it, either with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/3848797), which is found on the bottom of your [Questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3848797/tarvo-m%C3%A4esepp?tab=questions), or, as mentioned by @S.L.Barth, by checking the checkbox 'Show deleted posts' on the bottom of your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3848797/tarvo-m%C3%A4esepp?tab=reputation).

(Note that only *you* can see your own recently deleted questions - we can't check this for you.)

Comment: @Glorfindel I know all that but about the reputation thing. I just had 160 of it and for some reason now I have 155 and the graph do not show that I lost it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth thanks - I didn't even know about the checkbox.

Comment: I think there are more undiscovered stuff here :)

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp your rep issue might simply be bevause meta shows a cached version of your rep from the main site.